# $(event.target) fetching all elements I am touching

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I right click on text **[ Hello 1 ]**, and if I `console.log($(event.target));`, I will get 1 item.

Now if I right click on text **[ Hello 2 ]**, now if I `console.log($(event.target));`, I will get 2 items.

Similarly if I do it 3rd time I'll get 3.

Why is this happening and how can I make sure `$(event.target)` only fetches the last one I acted on ?

Comment: You should know by now that you should show the information necessary to answer the question w/o using speculation.  in this case, your HTML and JavaScript are required

Answer (score 0):

I think the information you presented is not enough to give accurate answer but target.event property returns the element that triggered the event. The target property gets the element on which the event originally occurred, opposed to the **currentTarget** property, which always refers to the element whose event listener triggered the event. so I think you should try **event.currentTarget** instead of **event.target.**